# How to merge table cells into a "T" shape in HTML?

Tags: html, merge, html-table

How to merge the two blank cells (one above 'Be' and one above 'B') with big blank space in the middle? I tried colspan and rowspan in different ways and still don't know how to do it.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tw5SE.png

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ex10.css">
</head>
<body>
<table style="width:800px;">
<tr class="tr1">
<th>I</th>
<th>II</th> 
<th>III</th>
<th>IV</th>
<th>V</th>
<th>VI</th>
<th>VII</th>
</tr>
<tr class="tr2">
<td>H</td>
<td class="tr1"></td>
<td colspan="3" rowspan="3"></td>
<td></td>
<td>He</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Li</td>
<td>Be</td>
<td>B</td>
<td>Ne</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tr4">
<td>Na</td>
<td>Mg</td>
<td>Al</td>
<td>Ar</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tr5">
<td>K</td>
<td>Ca</td>
<td>Sc</td>
<td>Ti</td>
<td>V</td>
<td>Ga</td>
<td>Kr</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tr1, th{
color: red;
width: 110px;
}

td{
width: 110px;
height: 54px;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: Calibri;
}

td:first-child {
background-color: #b4eba8;
}

td:nth-child(2):not(.tr1){
background-color: #76f9fd;
}

td:last-child{
background-color: #fadb47;
}
```

Comment: You can't. You can only merge cells to form rectangular (or square) areas. You could merge the row between Hydrogen and Helium, followed by merging the square between Beryllium, Boron, Magnesium and Aluminium. Or alternately, you could style the two little squares you have next to Hydrogen and Helium so that they didn't have a right border and a left border respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structurally you can't... but with css you can do it appear, here's your "only-visual" solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/fe74c5cq/

```
.bigtd{
  border:none;
}
.tdForT
{
  border-left:none;
}
.tr1{
  border-right:none;
}
```

take a look at css section, these three classes on the top made the trick (obviously I've put it in the right elements), you should be aware that the border that you see in a natural table, seems to be all "single" borders, but instead, when they are between a cell and another, they are twice!

You see a "single" border because in CSS there's a the property "border-collapse" for table valorized with "collapse" value.

So, when you want to make a border desappear, you must take it away from all adjacent elements.